# own len function with recursion in Go

Tags: recursion, go, slice

I'm trying to build simple function to count elements in slice (like len) It must be simple (without additional libs) and with recursion. The problem is when i try to check is slice is empty (is nul).

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  x := []int{1, 2, 3}
  fmt.Println(len2(x))
}
func len2(s []int) int {
  if s == nil {
    return 0
  }
  return 1 + len2(s[1:])
}
```

the result it should be in this example '3'.

It's broken in if s == nil:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

Comment: I forgot to add, that I build my own len. I can't use build-in len function.

Comment: You simply **cannot** do this. This is totally impossible: The recursion must end (the `s==nil` case in your code) and this can be done only with the builtin len function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not a solution with better performance than `len` but an implementation that does not use any extra libraries and depends on recursion to find length

```
func len2(s []int) (count int) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            count = 0
        }
    }()

    return 1 + len2(s[1:])
}
```

Here is sample code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x []int = nil
    var x1 = []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    var x2 = []int{}
    var x3 = make([]int, 10, 20)
    fmt.Println(len2(x))
    fmt.Println(len2(x1))
    fmt.Println(len2(x2))
    fmt.Println(len2(x3))
}

func len2(s []int) (count int) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            count = 0
        }
    }()

    return 1 + len2(s[1:])
}
```

Checkout the same in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L4dPom9kwg)

Comment: Please add reasons for negative votes , especially when the answer is an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

It panics because you have no valid termination condition.

When your `len2()` is called with a non-`nil` empty slice, it attempts to slice it like `s[1:]`, which will be a runtime panic.

Instead of checking for `nil` slice, check if the slice is empty by comparing its length to `0`:

```
func len2(s []int) int {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return 1 + len2(s[1:])
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qkb_ZQxZ9b).

If you can't use the builtin `len()` function (which you already did in your solution), you may use the `for ... range`:

```
func len2(s []int) int {
    size := 0
    for i := range s {
        size = i + 1
    }
    return size
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wbrYy2rSKN).

And if it must be recursive, then for example:

```
func len2(s []int) int {
    size := 0
    for range s {
        size = 1 + len2(s[1:])
        break
    }
    return size
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5ghvRHrg5_).

But know that these are awful solutions compared to using the builtin `len()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use len() func, you can use [cap()](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#cap)

```
func main() {
  x := []int{1, 2, 3}
  fmt.Println(len2(x))
}

func len2(s []int) int {

 if cap(s) == 0 {
    return 0
 }

  return 1 + len2(s[1:])
}
```

[Try it again](https://play.golang.org/p/BbEC_jXxnj)

**Original Answer:**

In order to check if an array (slice) is empty, you should use the function [len()](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len)

```
  if len(s) == 0 {
    return 0
  }
```

[Try it](https://play.golang.org/p/XeUetiei1X)

Comment: i want to create own len function - that is i don't want do use embedded len function.

Comment: Not guaranteed by the language spec to work with all implementations.

Answer (score -1):

If you can leave without recursion here is a function that does not use `len()` and should be faster then re-slicing recursively.

```
func len2(s []int) (count int) {
  for i := range s {
    count = i + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: An alternative with recursion that uses the same range loop protections (and never actually loops, it just uses the range operator as a ghetto `len` call without actually calling `len`): https://play.golang.org/p/KeXUfnJAr3